# How can I test if two variables are correlated with each other with a pre-specified coefficient?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

How can I test the hypothesis that two variables are correlated with each other at r=1?

I am not looking for a Pearson or Spearman test. That can give me a p<0.05 if the two variables are correlated regardless of the correlation coefficient.

Comment: As I explain at the duplicate question, there is no testing. An empirical correlation less than $1$ means that true correlation is not $1$. Do you mean that you want to test a particular regression coefficient value? That is a distinct question with a straightforward answer, and testing is absolutely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PeterFlom provides a useful link to a similar question. If you are only interested in testing whether the correlation is equal to $1$, there isn't much to say (see the post).

If you are interested in the more general hypothesis,
$$H_0: \rho = r,$$
as suggested by the questions title, then *Bootstrapping* provides a straightforward and effective approach.

We start by simulating some data

```
set.seed(111)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n, 0, 1)
y <- rnorm(x, x, 0.025)
```

The sample correlation here is $\hat \rho = 0.9957$. The sampling distribution of $\hat\rho$ can be well approximated via the Bootstrap algorithm.

```
B <- 1e5 # Number of bootstrap samples
boot <- rep(NA, B)
for(i in 1:B){
  ind <- sample(1:n, n, replace=TRUE)
  boot[i] <- cor(x[ind], y[ind])
}

hist(boot, xlim=c(0.99, 1),
     xlab="", main="Bootstrap distribution for sample correlation")
```

[image: Bootstrap distribution]

If you would like to test against a two-sided alternative hypothesis
$$H_0: \rho \neq r_0,$$
the following code will suffice

```
r0 <- 0.997 # Value we want to test for

tail1 <- mean(boot < r0)
tail2 <- mean(boot > r0)
p_val <- 2*min(tail1, tail2)
```

For the value `r0 = 0.997` we get a p-value of $0.071$. For the value `r0=1`, we get a p-value of exactly $0$, as expected. When $r = 1$ this test procedure can only produce of p-value of either $0$ or $1$, in agreement with the answer linked by @PeterFlom.